# SQLite calculate maximum number of attempts

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to find out what is the greatest number of times a student has submitted an assignment. This works in some occasions, but seems to select only the first assignment id and calculates the number of submissions for that.

```
SELECT S.name, MAX(COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Assignments A WHERE A.student_id = S.id GROUP BY A.assignment_id), 0))
FROM Students S LEFT JOIN Assignments A ON S.id = A.student_id GROUP BY S.id;
```

```
Students       Submissions
+---+------+   +---+------------+--------------+
|id |name  |   |id |student_id  | assignment_id|
+---+------+   +---+------------+--------------+  
| 1 | Lisa |   | 1 | 1          |      1       |
| 2 | Andy |   | 2 | 1          |      1       |
| 3 | Luke |   | 3 | 2          |      1       |
+---+------+   | 4 | 3          |      3       |
               | 5 | 2          |      1       |
               | 6 | 2          |      2       |
               | 7 | 2          |      1       |
               +---+------------+--------------+
```

So from these tables I want:

```
+------+-----+
| Lisa |  2  |
| Andy |  3  |
| Luke |  1  | 
+------+-----+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
SELECT S.name, Max(A.Cnt) as Cnt
FROM Students S LEFT JOIN 
(Select student_id,Assignment_id,count(*) as Cnt 
from Assignments Group by student_id,Assignment_id
)A ON S.id = A.student_id 
GROUP BY S.name;
```

In the sub query, we calculate the Count of attempts per assignment for a student and then map it to the Students table. Finally, we get the max of cnt by grouping at Student level. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Join `Students` to a query that uses `MAX()` window function to return the max attempts for each student:

```
select distinct s.name, t.counter
from Students s inner join (
  select student_id, max(count(*)) over (partition by student_id) counter
  from Submissions
  group by student_id, assignment_id
) t on t.student_id = s.id
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rz7LKZSVwMUsRTXVzV33eu/1).
Results:

```
| name | counter |
| ---- | ------- |
| Lisa | 2       |
| Andy | 3       |
| Luke | 1       |
```